# differential equation uniqueness thm

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In class we showed the two functions $y_1(x)=x$ and $y_2(x)=x^2$ had a Wronskian which vanished at the single point $x = 0$ and concluded that they could not be solutions of a second order linear homogeneous differential equation. But they satisfy $$x^2y''− 2xy' + 2y = 0$$
 What gives?

Comment: Yes, they are solutions indeed. This is known as an Euler-Cauchy equation. Compute the Wronskian for the pair of solutions. It is not zero for x different from zero. For clear reasons, we exclude $x=0$. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I can see your confusion, you are thinking probably of a homogeneous, constant coefficient, 2nd order equation like $\alpha y''+\beta y'+\gamma y=0$.

As mentioned in the comment, this is an Euler-Cauchy equation, which has general form:

$$ax^2y''+bxy'+cy=0 $$

The general form of the (trial) solution of this equation is $y(x)=x^r$.Computing its first and second derivatives, we get:

$$y'(x)=rx^{r-1}$$
$$y''(x)=r(r-1)x^{r-2}$$

Plug in the above derivatives to the equation and get:

$$ax^2r(r-1)x^{r-2}+bxrx^{r-1}+cx^r=ar(r-1)x^r+brx^r+cx^r=[ar(r-1)+br+c]x^r=0$$

In order to have a (non-trivial) solution, we require $y(x)=x^r \neq 0$.

Solve the characteristic equation $F(r)=r(r-1)-2r+2=r^2-3r+2=(r-1)(r-2)=0$ and you have two roots $r_1=1$ and $r_2=2$.

Thus, the general solution is $$y(x)=c_1x^{r_1}+c_2x^{r_2}=c_1x+c_2x^2$$ 
Note that this is only true when $x>0$. For $x<0$, just take absolute values and instead have:

$$y(x)=c_1x^{r_1}+c_2x^{r_2}=c_1|x|+c_2|x|^2$$
The Wronskian determinant gives:

$$W[y_1,y_2](x)= x(2x)-x^2=2x^2-x^2=x^2$$

The solutions $y_1=x$ and $y_2=x^2$ are thus a fundamental pair for $x\neq0$.

So, really the problem should have given a statement like $x > 0$ (or even $x<0$).